# Epsilon delta language of limits approaching infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I understand the concept of how to write limits in epsilon delta style when you have a limit like this, $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.  But how would I write it when $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = c$, for example?  Would it be enough to show that $f(x)$ is bounded above or below?  That is, would it be enough to show that $\exists M\in \Bbb R$ s.t. $\forall x\in \Bbb R, f(x) \lt M$ or $f(x) \gt M$? My professor hasn't really explained a whole lot about limits at $\infty$, so I am looking for outside advice. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=c$ means for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $x_0$ such that $|f(x)-c|<\varepsilon$ whenever $x>x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Just being bounded certainly won't be enough to make a reasonable definition of a limit at infinity: The sine function is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, but it keeps oscillating back and forth between $-1$ and $1$, so it's not sensible to say it has a limit at infinity.

Morally, we write

$$\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$$

if for all $x$ really close to $c$, $f(x)$ is really close to $L$. The same idea holds at infinity: For $x$ close to infinity (namely, really large), we want $f(x)$ close to $L$. I'll leave it to you to translate exactly what this means, more formally.